# Changing Snitch on live cluster in datastax 4.5

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have 8 nodes in one region and now i want to add new node in other region.Presently i m using ec2snitch  ,after adding node to new region i need to change snitchs of all nodes to ec2 multiregion snitch.

Now my question is, does this change will impact my current running cluster? and what would be the best practice for doing this .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a rolling restart changing to ec2 multi region snitch before adding the new node.  It should not impact your running cluster.  Though I would suggest you bring up a test cluster briefly to test making the change.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a rolling restart from Opscenter:

1. Click Nodes in the left pane.
2. In the contextual menu select Restart
   from the Cluster Actions dropdown.
3. Set the amount of time to wait after restarting each node, select whether the node should be
   drained before stopping, and then click Restart Cluster.

See more details here:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/opscRestartingCluster_t.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the DataStax documentation for [switching snitches](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_switch_snitch.html). I found that to be useful when I switched to the GossipingPropertiesFileSnitch. I also had to edit cassandra-rackdc.properties on all nodes before doing the rolling restart.

Even though my topology didn't change, I followed the instruction in the reference. Stopped all the nodes, restarted them (start with the seeds), then ran 'nodetool repair' and 'nodetool cleanup' on all nodes.